# Troubleshooting codeigniter "Unable to locate the model you have specified..." error

Tags: php, codeigniter, module, ion-auth, codeigniter-3

I have been developing a web application using CodeIgniter on my Mac with no issues whatsoever. I am using the Ion Auth library for user authentication. I have no ported the site the production server and I am getting the following error:

```
An Error Was Encountered

Unable to locate the model you have specified: Ion_auth_model
```

All of the posts on here seem to be file placement or the case of the filename or class name. I have quadruple checked the ion auth model code..

/application/models/ion_auth_model.php

```
class Ion_auth_model extends CI_Model{
   ...
}
```

The only place the model is loaded is in the ion auth library:

/applicaiton/libraries/ion_auth.php

```
$this->load->model('ion_auth_model');
```

And most frustratingly - it works perfectly on my development system. The only differences between my prod and dev environments is the database config (I even have it in development mode now so I might seen an error.

No log entry, no helpful error on the page, no help at all from CodeIgniter to direct me where the error is coming from.

Can anyone point me in the right direction to troubleshoot this????

Comment: Within the library, what does `echo APPPATH;` produce?

Comment: echo APPPATH; returns "/home/whiteatom/new-app/application/" - the correct path for my application folder.

Comment: Make sure your file names are correctly formated. Class file names must be Ucfirst and everything else in lowercase. In your case Ion_auth_model.php instead of "ion_auth_model"

Comment: All of my model have lowercase file names, with an ucfirst class name.. is that not correct??

Comment: If you are using codeigniter 3, then the filenames should start with upper case.

Comment: `Unable to locate the model` that error message help you to know what is the problem.Either you missed file name wrong or class definition wrong.Try to figure out and also see codeigniters documentation

Comment: AHHH OK.. that is not clear in the stack overflow responses at all. Thanks. I also see that because I'm on a Mac, the filesystem is not case sensitive - i guess that's why it worked on my dev system. Thanks!

Comment: @whiteatom, How did you fix it ?

Comment: models need to have UC first file names - difficult to see on a non-case sensitive file system like my mac.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As said in the comments : Your model's filename must start with an uppercase. In your case, Ion_auth_model.php.

See https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/changelog.html#version-3-0-0

> changed filenaming convention (class file names now must be Ucfirst
>   and everything else in lowercase).

Answer (score 0):

your autoload configuration ( application/config/autoload.php )

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('ion_auth');
```

it worked for me, please try it...